# Find the range and number of solution of equation involving inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

$$\text{Paragraph Based Question}$$
$\text{Let $\displaystyle \alpha  = 2 \tan^{-1} \frac{1}{2} + \sin^{-1} \frac{3}{5} $ and $\displaystyle \beta= \sin^{-1} \frac{12}{13} + \cos^{-1} \frac{4}{5} +\cot ^{-1} \frac{16}{63} $ be such that $2\sin\alpha $ and $\cos \beta$ are roots of the equation $x^2-ax+b=0$ , where $a,b \in  R$}$

$\text{1.The value of}$ $$\tan^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\cos^{-1} \left( \sin \frac{\alpha}{2}\right) \right) -  1 \right)$$ $\text{(in terms of $\alpha$ or $\beta$ )}$

$\text{2.The range of}$ $$f(x)=\cot^{-1}(x^2+bx)$$

$\text{3.The number of solution(s) of the equation} $ $$|b|\sin^{-1} x =(a-b)x$$

My work 
$$ \sin\alpha =\frac{24}{25}$$
$$ \cos\beta =-1$$
$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1-\sin \frac{\alpha}{2}}{ \sin \frac{\alpha}{2}}\right)$$
$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$$

$$a=\frac{23}{25} ,b=- \frac{48}{25} $$
$$f(x)=\cot^{-1}(x^2- \frac{48}{25} x)$$
$$ \sin^{-1} x=\frac{71x}{48}$$

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Since $\sin x < x$, then $\sin^{-1} x > x$, so how can the last line be true?

Comment: @martycohen only zero satisfy them.

Comment: How articifial/uneducative such questions (homework ?)

Comment: @JeanMarie Test question